# Add finding attribute by name in Opencart Admin panel: Catalog - Attributes - Attributes

Tags: attributes, find, opencart

How to implement Attribute to find his own name in the admin area in Opencart : Products - Attributes - Attributes? Is that there is a separate field and simply by driving into the field and displays the name of the attribute is an attribute, as usual searching for items in the admin by name, but only with attribute

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to understand what you are asking, but if you are trying to use attributes for products then you must first define them at catalog>attributes>attributes.

To List attributes in the Products tab you will need edit these files

```
admin>view>template>catalog>product_form.tpl
admin>controller>catalog>product.php
```

If your understanding of PHP or Opencart isn't very strong it will help you to copy data from the attribute.php controller to the product.php controller.

As for the search function, this is something I haven't done before but you could try using the search function on the front of the website as reference.

I recommend working through this as best you can then asking more questions if or when you get stuck.

***Update**

Ok so since HTML is your strenth it will be smartest to start from there. Open any of these files (the ones that have the data you need).

```
admin>view>template>catalog>attribute_form.tpl
admin>view>template>catalog>attribute_group_form.tpl
admin>view>template>catalog>attribute_group_list.tpl
admin>view>template>catalog>attribute_list.tpl
```

Then work backwards with what you see. The tpl will show variables that look like $attribute, track these back to

```
admin>controller>catalog>attribute.php
admin>controller>catalog>attribute_group.php
```

And you will see how all the code is used to pull the data from the model and format it if necessary.

Comment: It's image of my idea http://imglink.ru/show-image.php?id=285e21dc30dcb4f5646a72a1a7867673

Comment: You want all attributes listed, and then to be able to search through them?

Comment: Yes, atributes to be able to search, sorry for my bad English

Comment: I updated my answer for you, hopefully it gives you a good place to start.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understud which of code copy and paste to product.php, please help, i load files to http://rghost.ru/download/38929961/ec0b5bafb88502f1c7c40d44cfb154bf81773aa6/Search.zip

Comment: It's not as simple as a copy and paste, it will realistically take a couple of hours. Are you experienced in HTML or PHP?

Comment: I am not experienced PHP, html i know

Comment: Thanks I small understood, but what about search function ? How I can Join Attributes (from database) with search function? Can you help whith search?

Comment: The search function will be very complex and beyond my abilites. It may be helpful to look at this file for code reference 'catalog/controller/product/search.php' and then for your needs you will need to write and implement javascript also.